# How to convert pptx files to pdf files in Databricks (linux), maintaining font color and images

Tags: python, linux, pdf-generation, databricks, python-pptx

I am trying to convert a pptx file to pdf in Databricks, maintaining the design and structure of the original pptx file.
From what I found online there are ways to do that using comtypes and win32 libraries on windows, but since Databricks is built on top of linux, cant use these libraries.
So for this I used python-pptx with reportlab and managed to convert a pptx file to pdf.

The issues with that are:

1. The output file only contains text, no images, no color (cant figure out how to do that with python-pptx library)
2. The output file does not include text found within shapes
3. Text from multiple slides on one page.

Here is my code implementation:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer


pptx_file_path = '/dbfs/input.pptx' 
presentation = Presentation(pptx_file_path)


slide_contents = []
for slide in presentation.slides:
    slide_text = ""
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if hasattr(shape, "text"):
            slide_text += shape.text + "\n"
    slide_contents.append(slide_text)

# Create a PDF using reportlab
pdf_file_path = '/dbfs/output.pdf'
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_file_path, pagesize=letter)
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
elements = []
for content in slide_contents:
    elements.append(Paragraph(content, styles['Normal']))
    elements.append(Spacer(1, 12))
doc.build(elements)
```